# Add domain users to a SharePoint group

Tags: wss-3.0

I want to add a domain user to a SharePoint group by using the people picker. Unfortunately the users cannot be found. I checked the settings in

```
Central Administration > Application Management > Authentication Providers
```

and everything is okay. I can even add a domain user in

```
Central Administration > Application Management > Policy for Web Application
```

I read in the internet, that the server have to be integrated to the domain before installing SharePoint. In my case SharePoint was installed and then the Server was integrated.

Do i need to change any configuration? I am using WSS 3.0.

Thank you for any help:)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the people picker with an STSADM command. I think that should help:

stsadm –o setproperty –pn peoplepicker-searchadforests –pv domain:somedomain -url http://somewebapp

(taken from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263460(office.12).aspx)

Comment: At first thank you Bernd. I tried this command and the operation ended with "operation completed successfully". Unfortunately i still cannot find people in the people picker. You have any other thoughts?

Comment: How exactly do you use the people picker? Did you try to enter a valid user name (domain\user) in the text box and click on the check names icon? Can that find the user or does it show a read curly line under the input?

Comment: If I use the user name (domain\user), I'll get "No exact match was found." By the way if i gave a policy to a user, I won't find them in the picker, too. But if the user has visited the sharepoint site, i am able to find him.
thanks Bernd

Comment: Is the server in the same AD domain as the user?

Comment: Ok, that sounds like there is no problem with the AD but only with the people picker, still. Are you sure you were using the right domain name in the STSADM command? E.g. the logon domain (in drop-down when logging onto a machine) might show 'corp', the domain name could be 'corp.net' or something else. You should find some errors in the ULS (SharePoint) log that there are no trusted AD forrests and/or domains.

Comment: @Kit Menge: Yes, the user and the Ad domain are the same
@ Bernd: i used the right domain name